# Connect Twilio studio flow with Google Calendar, create event

Tags: node.js, twilio

This code is working fine in replit compilator.
I want to put the same thing in twilio studio flow function, but I can't do it.
I just want to take the date/month and add the event in my google calendar.
can someone help me with it?
clientMonth, clientDay this variable are dynamic , thos two digis is similar.

Dependensis is googleapis-^65.0.0
Assets=auth.json
Env variable is calendarId-***** and GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS = /auth.json

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs').promises;

exports.handler = async function (context, _event, callback) {
// Google calendar API settings
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
const authJson = JSON.parse(
  await fs.readFile(Runtime.getAssets()[context.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS].path)
);

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
authJson.client_email,
null,
authJson.private_key,
SCOPES
);
const calendar = google.calendar({version : "v3",auth});

const TIMEOFFSET = '+02:00';
var clientMonth = 5;
var clientDay = 23;
var todayDate = new Date();
var clientDate = new Date(todayDate.getFullYear(), clientMonth-1, 
clientDay);


const dateTimeForCalander = () => {
//let todayDate = new Date();
let year = clientDate.getFullYear();
let month = clientDate.getMonth()+1;
if (month < 10) {
    month = `0${month}`;
}
let day = clientDate.getDate() ;
if (day < 10) {
    day = `0${day}`;
}
let hour = todayDate.getHours();
if (hour < 10) {
    hour = `0${hour}`;
}
let minute = todayDate.getMinutes();
if (minute < 10) {
    minute = `0${minute}`;
}
let newDateTime = `${year}-${month}-${day}T${hour}:${minute}:00.000${TIMEOFFSET}`;

let event = new Date(Date.parse(newDateTime));

let startDate = event;
// Delay in end time is 1
let endDate = new Date(new 
Date(startDate).setHours(startDate.getHours()+1));

return {
    'start': startDate,
    'end': endDate
};
};
let dateTime = dateTimeForCalander();
console.log(dateTime);

// Event for Google Calendar
let Clientevent = {
'summary': `This is the summary.`,
'description': `This is the description.`,
'start': {
  'dateTime': dateTime.start,
  'timeZone': 'Europe/Tirane'
},
'end': {
   'dateTime': dateTime.end,
    'timeZone': 'Europe/Tirane'
}
 };

 function insertEvent (eventi) {

    let response = calendar.events.insert({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: context.calendarId,
        resource: eventi
    });
    
}

 response.setBody({
  success: true,
  message: insertEvent(Clientevent),
})

return callback(null,response );
}
```

Comment: When you say you "can't do it" in a Twilio Function, what do you mean? Your code doesn't seem to include a handler function for a Twilio Function?

Comment: 1. It means I can't insert the event I want in google claendar.

Comment: 2. I add the function and still not working. I will make the changes

Answer (score 0):

I’m on my phone, so apologies for a brief answer. I believe the issue is that you are performing an asynchronous task to add the event to the calendar, but you are returning the callback synchronously on the last line of the function. When you call the callback function, all processes started within the function are terminated. So if you still have an asynchronous API call running, calling the callback will end that call.

Make sure that you only call the callback when all asynchronous tasks that you perform within the function are completed. I think the asynchronous call you need to wait for is the call to `calendar.events.insert` .

Comment: Do not worry, I'm thankful you are helping me. In my understanding is that I have problem in my logic of how I call the function inside of function or I don't know. But please can u try the code in your studio and explain what u did, I'm a beginner in Twilio and node js.

Comment: @LucianoGjinaj how much do you know about asynchronous functions?

Comment: not to much but I know something like that is about to set the time for function because sometime needed more time to execute. So I need to create the function like   "async function { 'and use await'}", because it take time to read API

Comment: `calendar.events.insert` is an asynchronous function. Check out the docs for googleapis to see how to use it asynchronously: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#using-the-client-library

Comment: `async function insertEvent (eventi) {
    let response = await calendar.events.insert({
        auth: auth,
        calendarId: context.calendarId,
        resource: eventi
    });`
       }

Comment: u mean I need to use await to call `calendar.event.insert`

Comment: That might work, give it a go and see!

Comment: No still is not working. :(

Comment: Do you get an error? What is it doing?

Comment: I'm so sorry for letting you wait, I doesn't show any error the function is success but doesn't insert the event.

Comment: Are you `await`ing the result of calling `insertEvent`?

Comment: I adjusted the function by doing the twilio async function and using wait unnecessarily another function and to call it again and it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion to look at the asynchronous function I appreciate.

Comment: Oh, glad to hear you fixed it! If you needed another `await` then it wasn’t unnecessary!